# Football DataFrame - Setting Season From Date

Tags: python, pandas

This should be a simple task, but I cannot figure it out!

I have a dataframe containing English Premier league football data. All I want to do is to add a season column & use the date to set the season e.g. Date = 2021-08-13, season = 2021.

[Prem league](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv4kR.png)

But try as I might - cannot make it work. How do i do this?
Last attempt:

```
def get_season(row):
if (row['Date'] > pd.to_datetime("01/08/2021")):
    season = "2021"
prem_data_new['Season'] = prem_data_new.apply(lambda row: get_season(row),axis = 1)
```

prem_data_new

Comment: `prem_data_new['Season'] = np.where(prem_data_new['Date'] > '2021-08-01', '2021', np.nan)`? Also, what format is `01/08/2021` - mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy?

Comment: It’s datetime, but does the format matter?

Comment: Not the data type but the format of the date string: `'01/08/2021'` is ambiguous because I do not know if it is Jan. 8, 2021 or Aug. 1, 2021?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the prem_data_new['Date'] type.
2. If it is datetime use something like this

```
    prem_data_new['Season'] = prem_data_new['Date'].year
```

3. If not try

```
    prem_data_new['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(prem_data_new['Date'], errors='coerce')
```

and then get to point 2.

---

To get season, you can try this func:

```
def func(ser):
    lst = []
    for i in range(len(ser)):
      if ser[i].month < 8:
      lst.append(ser[i].year)
    else:
      lst.append(ser[i].year + 1)
    return lst

prem_data_new['Season'] = func(prem_data_new['Date'])
```

or

```
prem_data_new['Season'] = [x.year if x.month < 8 else x.year + 1 for x in prem_data_new['Date']]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the season is not just based on the year e.g. the 2020 season started 01-08-2020 , so a match played 31-07-20 is the 2019 season.

Comment: Ok, I've added another solution. Maybe it's not elegant, but should work

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the map function and define a function to return the year assignable to the dataframe field

Answer (score 0):

Since you are deciding the season based on the month and day (e.g. 1st of Aug), your function should compare the month and day of the date field.

**Demo:**

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

prem_data_new = pd.DataFrame({
    'div':['e0','e0','e0','e0','e0'],
    'date':['2021-08-13','2021-08-14','2020-07-30','2020-08-13','2021-08-01'],
    'hometown':['Brentford','Man United','Burnley','Chelesa','Everton',],
    'awayteam':['Arsenal','Leeds','Brighton','Crystal Palace','Southampton'],
    'fthg':[2,5,1,3,3],
    'ftag':[0,1,2,0,1],
    'hthg':[1,1,1,2,0],
    'htag':[0,0,0,0,1]
})

def get_season(row):
  date_ser = pd.to_datetime(row['date'])
  return date_ser.year if (date_ser.month >= 8 and date_ser.day >= 1) else date_ser.year - 1
prem_data_new['season'] = prem_data_new.apply(lambda row: get_season(row),axis = 1)

print(prem_data_new)
```

**Output:**

```
  div        date    hometown        awayteam  fthg  ftag  hthg  htag  season
0  e0  2021-08-13   Brentford         Arsenal     2     0     1     0    2021
1  e0  2021-08-14  Man United           Leeds     5     1     1     0    2021
2  e0  2020-07-30     Burnley        Brighton     1     2     1     0    2019
3  e0  2020-08-13     Chelesa  Crystal Palace     3     0     2     0    2020
4  e0  2021-08-01     Everton     Southampton     3     1     0     1    2021
```

Comment: That looks good ! Will try it later

Comment: Was so sure that would work ! Just get the error i was getting originally: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'int' so cannot compare the date time object with 8 etc.

Comment: @neilHouselander - Do not compare the `Timestamp` with `int`. As shown in my solution use `>=` to compare month, day etc.

Comment: Thanks missed a .year !  Str get an error probably a real newb mistake :
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @neilHouselander - I did not get you. What is the format of your date string - is it in the format `2021-08-13` or `13/08/2021`?

Answer (score 0):

To check if a date is within a season:

1. check if the season intersects newyear (`season.start.year !== season.end.year`)
2. If this is the case, **split the season** into two parts
3. Set all years the same (season start/end and date_to_check
4. Simply do a `start < date < end` check on these parts

This elïminates the year+1/year-1 problem instantly.

- [.NET linq query](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.SeasonChecker/blob/master/MintPlayer.SeasonChecker/SeasonChecker.cs#L83)
- [SQL query](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.SeasonChecker/blob/master/MintPlayer.SeasonChecker/CheckSeason.sql)
- [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pieterjandc/L3prwqmh/1/)